# Automagically put patent title in tooltip for links to individual patents on Google Patents

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks

So it seems [we will standardize on linking to Google Patents from mentions of patent numbers / codes / IDs](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/best-practices-for-linking-references-to-patent-numbers) (what are these things generally called by the way?)

It would be a neat and simple little feature to add then for the system to look up the referenced patent, extract the title, and it it to the HTML using the `title` attribute. I'm assuming you're already using a Google Patent API which would neatly provide this info.

Comment: There isn't actually a Google API to get this information, other than scraping the HTML.

Comment: @DavidFullerton: Really? That's annoying because I took my own lead and added the patent titles to the current patent number tags and in so doing discovered that longer titles are truncated )-: I had to look at the scanned images. So would you like to post a feature request on Google or should I? (My previous ones are languishing, maybe they'll be more impressed with your credentials!)

Comment: Well Google did have a deprecated [patent API that supported patent titles](https://developers.google.com/patent-search/v1/jsondevguide#json_response) )-: Here's some other patent web APIs I just turned up which may be of interest: [Boliven](http://www.boliven.com/bws/patents_api). The [European Patent Office also has a API](http://www.epo.org/searching/free/espacenet.html) which seems to be only for searching but the titles look scrape-able (no US patents of course).

Answer (score 4):

I would rather have the patent showcased in the sidebar — either under Linked, or in its own shiny box.

[image]

Comment: Also excellent. But you can have both. Would still be easy and if the list is long and the screen is small...

Answer (score 2):

The full text of a patent is available by typing in the number at http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/srchnum.htm.  The web page produced there includes quite a bit of other information but does not include Figures.

PDFs of patents, showing the published patent formatted in two columns per page and showing Figures (or Drawing Sheets), are available at http://www.pat2pdf.org.  These are not searchable PDFs.

There are also commercial sources such as Thompson-Reuters that will provide searchable PDFs of published patents or patent applications.