# Automatic tag wikis for individual patents

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

> [Also, tag the question with the patent number, like: us20090293106. The software will use this to automatically include a link in the sidebar to the patent.](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/best-practices-for-linking-references-to-patent-numbers/19#19)

It would be nice if creating such tags automatically pulled in some information about the patent into the tag wiki, such as:

- the title (also in the tag wiki excerpt)
- a link to the official patent office page (e.g. USPTO for US patents)
- the abstract
- references to related patents (divisional applications, international applications)
- other cover page information such as submission dates, inventor and assignee data, etc.

Comment: See also: http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/q/55/345 We should also consider auto-tagging.

Answer (score 1):

I think including an assignee, if there is one listed in the file, is critical. Under the AIA, applicants are not supposed to submit prior art through a process such as this but instead use an IDS.

Large company applicants are likely to have issues with their employees; they don't want them to comment on their own applications - again, this would be avoided by listing as assignee.

Large companies can be a wonderful source of input for AskPatents but not making it easy to see the assignee on the face of the question/posting is likely to have a chilling effect on participation by such groups.