# Should we find a way to avoid patent numbers as tags?

Tags: discussion

I see a [number](https://patents.stackexchange.com/revisions/5897/1) [of](https://patents.stackexchange.com/revisions/738/1) [questions](https://patents.stackexchange.com/revisions/5755/1) where the author have used the patent number as a tag.

It gets slightly more interesting when a high rep user [changes](https://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/6616/revisions) a [question](https://patents.stackexchange.com/posts/5622/revisions) from having a link to having a tag (and in the process removes the link in face of [guidance](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16/best-practices-for-linking-references-to-patent-numbers)).

The guidance from other site in stack exchange is that for a tag to exist you must be able to say that somebody has to be a subject-matter expert in what the tag describes.   I submit that no-one can be an expert in a single patent, but could the expert in the subject matter of the patent, and if so the subject matter should be the tag and not the patent number.

What are the rule here on this site for use of tags ?

How do we educate or enfoce better use of tags?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Including the patent number in the tags is actually by design. From [the answer you linked](https://patents.meta.stackexchange.com/a/19/1) that provided this guidance:

> ...tag the question with the patent number, like: us20090293106. The software will use this to automatically include a link in the sidebar to the patent.

Comment: I see -- I had not noticed that feature.